# Dependency version issue

Tags: android, android-studio, dependencies

I have this issue when compiling my project in Android Studio:

```markdown
     Dependency 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat-resources:1.6.1' requires 
     libraries and applications that
     depend on it to compile against version 33 or later of the
     Android APIs.

     :app is currently compiled against android-32.

     Also, the maximum recommended compile SDK version for Android Gradle
     plugin 7.2.1 is 32.

     Recommended action: Update this project's version of the Android Gradle
     plugin to one that supports 33, then update this project to use
     compileSdkVerion of at least 33.

     Note that updating a library or application's compileSdkVersion (which
     allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
     targetSdkVersion (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
     minSdkVersion (which determines which devices the app can be installed
     on).
```

How can I fix this issue? I'm not sure what I should do.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

File -> Project Structure -> Depencencies -> Modules -> app -> Dependency

Find `appcompat` and change *Requested Version* to `1.5.1`

[image: IDEA project structure]

That worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

This is a dependency version contrast issue just replace your appcompact and ktx with these

```
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.8.0'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.2'
```

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade your `compileSdk` and `targetSdk` to `33`

```
compileSdk 33
targetSdk 33
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved by changing the compileSdk version

```
android {
namespace '.......'
compileSdk 32
```

to

```
android {
namespace '.....'
compileSdk 33
```