# I developed and launched an app in AndroidStudio, but it closes immediately

Tags: android-studio

I am working my way through the AndroidStudio tutorial.
https://developer.android.com/codelabs/kotlin-android-training-get-started#5
I have created an EMPTY project by following this page.
I downloaded the Pixel4 R emulator as described in the tutorial.
However, when I try to run the app, it only shows as below and does not run on the emulator.

7:33:51 PM: Executing task...

7:33:51 PM: Task execution finished.

[image: 1]

I suspected an error, but no error is indicated.

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75431649/dependency-androidx-appcompatappcompat-resources1-6-1)

I have only rewritten build.gradle using this page as a reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MvHR5.png)

The toolbar looked like this.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bqs9b.png)

So I clicked on the elephant icon and changed it to app, and now I can run the emulator.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).